# How to use a common set of require.config values across multiple projects

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Is there a way I can provide some common values to require.config of different projects that have a dependency on a common project? The common project basically contains all the 3rd party libs and custom widgets which may be used by the projects.

eg. I have 3 projects Proj1, Proj2, Proj3. The common module they use is called 'shell'. And I have a set of require.config path and some router config code used by all 3 of them.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl:'parentFolder/',
    paths:{
        /*  Third party libs  */
        jquery:'shell/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1',
        json2: 'shell/lib/json/json2',
        underscore:'shell/lib/underscore/underscore',
        backbone:'shell/lib/backbone/backbone',
        handlebars:'shell/lib/handlebars/handlebars',

        /* Routers */
        externalRouter:'shell/common/util/externalRouter',

        /* My custom widgets */          
        datePicker:'shell/common/widget/datePicker',
        treeView:'shell/common/widget/TreeView',
        videoPlayer:'shell/common/widget/VideoPlayer',
   }
});
```

I want to maintain the above config code in one location and want the 3 projects to use it in their own require.config with the ability to add new config params.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in a number of ways, but the simplest is probably to leverage the fact that RequireJS allows you to define the config object as a global variable called `require` before `require.js` is loaded, and have the values applied automatically at startup.

So put your common configuration in a plain javascript source file that looks like this:

```
//common-config.js
require = {
    baseUrl:'parentFolder/',
    paths:{
        jquery:'shell/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1',
    }
};
```

And include it on the page **before** require.js:

```
<script src="common-config.js"></script>
<script src="require.js" data-main="main"></script>
```

You can then call `require.config` again in your main module with application-specific configuration, as you normally would. Note that if you define the `baseUrl` option, the `main` module will be referenced relative to that base URL, so you have to adjust the `data-main` attribute accordingly.

Documentation for this feature is [here](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).